# Windows Batch folder size

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

I need a command (like "dir") that lists all directories with their size. I need just a 1 level deepness but with the total size of a directory.

For example

```
>dirsize c:/mainfolder
    subfolder1  15640
    subfolder2 682310
    subfolder3 283550
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`diruse`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736515%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from the [Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15326):

```
diruse /* c:\mainfolder
```

or [`du`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) from Sysinternals:

```
du -l 1 -q c:\mainfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following into a file in the parent directory named `getdirsize.bat`

```
@echo off
set /a val=0
set /a tot=0
for /R %1 %%i in (*) do (
set /a val=%%i
set /a tot=!tot!+!val!
)
@echo %cd%:!tot!
```

Then run the command below from the parent directory.  Alternatively, you could install the [GNU coreutils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and substitute `du` for `getdirsize.bat` below.  I'm currently on a Linux system so can't test -- you may need to tweak this a little.

for /D %subdirs in (.*) do getdirsize.bat %subdirs